# Pandas remove daily seasonality from data by substracting daily mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a big amount of timeseries sensor data in a pandas dataframe. The resolution of the data is one observation every 15 minutes for 1 month for 876 sensors.

The data has some daily seasonality and some faulty measurements in single sensors on about 50% of the observations.

I want to remove the seasonality.

```
df.diff(periods=96)
```

This does not work, because then I have an outlier on 2 days (the day with the actual faulty measurement and the day after.

Therefore I wrote this snippet of code which does what it should and works fine:

```
  for index in df.index:
    for column in df.columns:
        df[column][index] = df[column][index] - (
            df[column][df.index % 96 == index % 96]).mean()
```

The problem is that this is incredibly slow.
Is there a way to achieve the same thing with a pandas function significantly faster?

Comment: Please provide a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by sharing a sample of `df` and the expected output inside a code block, so we can reproduce your problem and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a DataFrame/ Series should be your last resort, it's very slow.

In this case, you can use `groupby` + `transform` to compute the mean of each season for all the columns, and then subtract with from your DataFrame in a vectorized way.

Based on your code, it seems that this should work

```
period = 96
season_mean = df.groupby(df.index % period).transform('mean')
df -= season_mean
```

Or, if you want

```
period = 96
df = df.groupby(df.index % period).transform(lambda g: g - g.mean())
```